# How to find Robolectric version at runtime?

Tags: android, robolectric

Is there a way to retrieve Robolectric's version at runtime? My environment is under controlled library versioning and would like to make sure I run a certain test only if Robolectric has an specific version (for example, to avoid runtime known issues with it). For example:

```
@Test
public void should_do_x() {
    if (Robolectric.version >= supported_version) {
       //do something
       //validate something
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get. Are you running some tests with one version of Robolectric and others with another?

Comment: no. My use case is: there are some known issues with my current version of Robolectric, but given that versioning in my company is controlled I can't just upgrade to the next one. I want to have a guard so that tests affected by such known issues run only if the current Robolectric version is equal or higher to the one I need.

Comment: I would resolve it with build configurations - robolectricx and robolectricy, and put test sources in different configuration folders, and also define dependencies per configurations